# RavenDB: Return documents containing highest number of common fields

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have a an object as following:

```
public class DemoItem {
    public string ItemTitle {get;set;}
    public List<string> Tags {get;set;}
}
```

Suppose I have hundreds of them saved in RavenDB, each having hundreds of tags. What I want now is to be able to return 'n' DemoItems that have the highest number of common tags with the DemoItem I'm querying for. The n parameter may vary between 1 to 10 in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `MoreLikeThis` feature:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/client-api/session/how-to/use-morelikethis